# Accessing array as a struct *

Tags: c, arrays, memory, struct

This is one of those *I think this should work, but it's best to check* questions. It compiles and works fine on my machine.

Is this guaranteed to do what I expect (i.e. allow me to access the first few elements of the array with a guarantee that the layout, alignment, padding etc of the struct is the same as the array)?

```
struct thingStruct
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};


void f()
{
    int thingsArray[5];
    struct thingStruct *thingsStruct = (struct thingStruct *)&thingsArray[0];

    thingsArray[0] = 100;
    thingsArray[1] = 200;
    thingsArray[2] = 300;

    printf("%d", thingsStruct->a);
    printf("%d", thingsStruct->b);
    printf("%d", thingsStruct->c);
}
```

EDIT: Why on earth would I want to do something like this? I have an array which I'm mmapping to a file. I'm treating the first part of the array as a 'header', which stores various pieces of information about the array, and the rest of it I'm treating as a normal array. If I point the struct to the start of the array I can access the pieces of header data as struct members, which is more readable. All the members in the struct would be of the same type as the array.

Comment: I **think** it would be fine so long as you use a `#pragma` or something to disable padding on the struct.

Comment: Note that you can do this with GCC by adding `__attribute__(packed)` after the brace ending the struct definition.

Comment: For Windows compilers (also supported by GCC), I believe you can use `#pragma pack(0)` before the struct definition and `#pragma pack()` after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I have seen this done frequently, you cannot (meaning it is not legal, standard C) make assumptions about the binary layout of a structure, as it may have padding between fields.

This is explained in the comp.lang.c faq: http://c-faq.com/struct/padding.htmls

Comment: You're right... but i think it should work most of the time unless a compiler has some reason to add padding between items of the same type.

Answer (score 3):

Although it's *likely* to work in most places, it's still a bit iffy.  If you want to give symbolic names to parts of the header, why not just do:

```
enum { HEADER_A, HEADER_B, HEADER_C };

/* ... */.

printf("%d", thingsArray[HEADER_A]);
printf("%d", thingsArray[HEADER_B]);
printf("%d", thingsArray[HEADER_C]);
```

Answer (score 2):

As Evan commented on the question, this will probably work in most cases (again, probably best if you use #pragma pack to ensure their is no padding) assuming all the types in your struct are the same type as your array.  Given the rules of C, this is legal.

My question to you is "why?"  This isn't a particularly safe thing to do.  If a float gets thrown into the middle of the struct, this all falls apart.  Why not just use the struct directly?  This really ins't a technique that I'd recommend in most cases.

Comment: "Given the rules of C, this is legal."  Does this not violate the strict aliasing rules?

Comment: Hrm... you'd think it would, but gcc 4.4.3 doesn't complain, no matter what options I throw at it.  Possibly because the first member of the struct is the correct type, and hence there is no conflict?  I've seen this sort of code lots of times where a larger value is pointed at by a smaller type, and it makes me shudder every time.

Comment: Why? I'm mmapping an array to a file. I'm storing some header information at the start, and the rest I'm treating as an array. All values are of the same type (I wouldn't dream of mixing types!). I just thought it would be more readable to alias the header portion with descriptive strut members than indexes.

Comment: @Joe regarding the larger/smaller types comment it doesn't directly pertain to your question, it's just used as a common example when discussing string aliasing.

Comment: @Joe sorry, brain cramp, you were answering my "why" in the original answer.  In the case you describe, it sounds reasonable enough.  I might cringe a bit, but I'd probably let it go in a code review as long as there were some comments explaining whats going on.  Perhaps you could update the original question to describe how and why you are mmaping the array, it would make it easier for others to provide a more constructive response.

Comment: @Joe thanks for the edit, I hadn't realized I spelled Evan's name incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for representing a header and the rest of file data is using a structure like this:

```
struct header {
    long  headerData1;
    int   headerData2;
    int   headerData3;
    int   fileData[ 1 ];  // <- data begin here
};
```

Then you allocate the memory block with a file contents and cast it as `struct header *myFileHeader` (or map the memory block on a file) and access all your file data with

```
myFileHeader->fileData[ position ]
```

for arbitrary big `position`. The language imposes no restriction on the index value, so it's only your responsibility to keep your *arbitrary big* `posistion` within the actual size of the memory block you allocated (or the mapped file's size).

One more **important note:** apart from switching off the struct members padding, which has been already described by others, you should carefully choose data types for the header members, so that they fit the actual file data layout despite compiler you use (say, `int` won't change from 32 to 64 bits...)