# Printing the data in multiple structs

Tags: c, file, struct

I'm working with four differest structs, two of which are quite large. I have a function to write each value of each struct to a .txt file, but the code is very long and robust. I'm looking for a way of printing out each value without having to hard code each in, but everything I've found so far in my research indicates that hardcoding is the only way, but I figured I'd check on here before I give up completely. As it stands right now, my code looks like this:

```
char text[416];
    snprintf(text, 416, 
        "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d", 
        epsy.VBUS_voltage_mV,
        epsy.temp_internal_degC,
        epsy.status,
        batty.Z_pos_Camera_Temperature,
        batty.Z_neg_Camera_Temperature,
        batty.Y_pos_Camera_Temperature,
        batty.Y_neg_Camera_Temperature,
        batty.X_pos_Camera_Temperature,
        batty.FPGA_Temp_1,
        batty.FPGA_Temp_2,
        batty.Rx_Hinge_Temperature,
        batty.Bat_1_Vbat,
        batty.Bat_1_Ichg,
        batty.Bat_1_Idch,
        batty.Bat_1_MCU_Temp,
        batty.Bat_1_Temp_Therm,
        batty.Bat_1_Status,
        batty.Bat_2_Vbat,
        batty.Bat_2_Ichg,
        batty.Bat_2_Idch,
        batty.Bat_2_MCU_Temp,
```

... and it goes on for a while. (80 values)
Is there a simpler way of doing this? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: Try to use `memcpy`

Comment: I'd be tempted to write a short python script that reads the relavant header file(s) and writes the c code for you.

Comment: can you paste the structure definition?

Comment: ... along with a bit of search & replace editing.

Comment: There's no built-in shortcut for printing structures.

Comment: Are _all_ the `struct` members `int` and will be forwever?

Comment: the structs are too long to be posted here, wyc. Sorry!

Comment: And yes, they are all ints, though not all of the same size. most are uint8_t or uint16_t. There is one that is 4 bytes long

Comment: @ConnorOlsen Detail: then the members are not all `int`.  `int` is a single type.  There are all _integers_.

Comment: @ConnorOlsen I do [have a way](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/115143/29485) to handle something like this although I suspect it is more complex than you would desire.  Example `GPrintf(GP(epsy.VBUS_voltage_mV), " " GP(epsy.temp_internal_degC), " ",  GP(epsy.status), GP_eol);`

Comment: an `int` could take up to ~15 characters to print.  The code should allow for that.  Amongst other things, 80*(15+1) is a whole lot more than  416 (and remember need to allow for a space between each number, which s why the `+1`).  even if only allowed 5 columns for each number (+space) is larger than 416.  And then would need format specifications similar to `4.4%d `

Comment: were it me, to keep the code simple, I would write a table that contains the address of each of the 84 data items, then go through a loop, performing ``realloc()`, `strlen()`, sprintf()` and `strcat()` for each of the data items.  This will take a bit longer to execute, but is much less error prone and (after writing the initial code, never have to change anything but the table entries

Answer (score 2):

The following solution defines a `union` that combines the actual `struct` with it's integral members with an array of integral values in order to "view" the struct members as array elements accessible through subscription.

To make this save, we need to control the alignment, since the compiler might add padding between the data members. This would then let the "array-view" point to invalid memory and introduce undefined behaviour.

I suggest to use `#pragma pack(n)` to control the alignment. Note that the code may also work without this alignment thing, yet it might get a problem if data members of other type are introduced before or after the "integral block" (This would also require to offset the "array-view", but that's not shown here).

The surrounding union is required to guarantee that the array and the struct are actually aligned correctly; otherwise, a cast from a struct to an array might introduce undefined behaviour.

I'm aware that `#pragma pack` is not portable and that it affects the memory layout and probably speed. Yet it is supposed to work on most compilers, and I think it is needed for controlling alignment in order to avoid UB:

```
#pragma pack(4)     /* set alignment to 4 byte boundary */

#define nrOfMyPackedDataElements 3

union MyPackedData {

    struct {
        int32_t firstInt;
        int32_t secondInt;
        int32_t thirdInt;
    } data;

    int32_t array[nrOfMyPackedDataElements];
};

#pragma pack()      /* reset alignment to compiler default */

int main() {

    union MyPackedData data;
    data.data.firstInt = 10;
    data.data.secondInt = 20;
    data.data.thirdInt = 30;

    for (int i=0; i < nrOfMyPackedDataElements; i++) {
        printf("%d ",data.array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C11 you could rewrite your `struct`s using unnamed structures and union fields.

Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct dir_t
{
    int pos;
    int neg;
};

struct cam_temp_t
{
    dir_t x;
    dir_t y;
    dir_t z;
};

// it seems that you have only ints in your structure...
#define TOTAL_N_INTS 8

struct batty_t
{
    union
    {
        int data_[TOTAL_N_INTS];  
        struct
        {
            struct cam_temp_t camera_temperature;
            int               fpga;  // you get it...
            int               bat;
        }
    };
};

int main(void)
{
    struct batty_t example = {
        .camera_temperature = {
            .x = {3, 4},
            .y = {5, 6},
            .z = {7, 8}
        },
        .fpga = 1,
        .bat = 2
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_N_INTS; ++i )
    {
        printf("%4d", example.data_[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Of course if you have different types, you should use different arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing an `int` array via a `struct` and visa-versa like this answer might be valid, might not.  Yet I am now not so confident for its use with general types.  Leaving this as wiki for anyone to add/amend/delete.

---

OP later commented that the `struct` members are not all `int`.  Oh well.

---

If all members are and forever will be `int` ...

Access each member, one at a time by `int` offset.

Some untested code to illustrate the idea:

```
int print_int_struct(char *dest, size_t d_size, const void *st, size_t s_size) {
  if (s_size % sizeof(int) != 0) {
    return -1; // bad struct size
  }
  size_t n = s_size / sizeof(int);
  const char *delimiter = "";
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int d;
    memcpy(&d, st, sizeof d);
    st = (char*) st + sizeof(int);
    int len = snprintf(dest, d_size, "%s%d", delimiter, d);
    if (len < 0 || (size_t) len >= d_size) {
      return -1; // out of room
    }
    dest += len;
    d_size -= len;
    delimiter = " ";
  }
  return 0;
}
struct s1 {
  int VBUS_voltage_mV;
  int temp_internal_degC;
  int status;
  ...
};

struct s1 st = ...;
char buf[1024];
print_int_struct(buf, sizeof buf, &st, sizeof st);
puts(buf);
```

Comment: Couldn't it be that the compiler lays out a structure with consecutive ints in a different way than an array of ints (arrays may not introduce padding, structs may)?

Comment: @StephanLechner That is a very valid concern, yet I am confident the answer is no.  Even so far as to say that it applies to all types, not just `int`.   I'd have to do some work to cite that though.  [This implies a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4512019/2410359), yet it is not so authoritative.

Comment: If an `int` is the same size as the machine's word size (which it usually is) there probably won't be padding between a struct made entirely of `int`s... though strictly speaking it is up to the compiler.

Comment: @GovindParmar Its those [unicorn machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendary_creature) that may pad 32-bit `int` members on 64-bit boundaries that could break things. IAC, to solve OP's issues 1) more info would help and 2) IMO, writing a print function per `struct` is not so bad.